# cfselect query from a getter

Tags: coldfusion

If you have a cfselect command that builds its options list from a getter function, how do you write it?

```
cfselect name="FooID" query="scope.functionname.getFoo()" Display="FooName" value="FooID" />
```

Or maybe, as someone said in a previous post, I should build the options list in a cfsavecontent and therefore it will be cached.

Comment: actually, have you ever thought of storing the actual query object in Application scope? Then you can <cfselect query="application.myQuery" ...>

Comment: Henry -- see his previous question.  :-)  It's about slmost exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cfset myQuery = scope.functionname.getFoo()>
<cfselect name="FooID" query="myQuery" Display="FooName" value="FooID" />
```

Query attribute = Name of query to populate drop-down list.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7afe.html

And yes, if the query doesn't change, and HTML is the only output you need, it's a good idea to cache the generated HTML.